# Javascript - get all combination of integer array by adding two elements

Tags: javascript, combinations

I have integer array with 10 elements. I want all the combinations by adding two elements.

Comment: 2 for loops, and you're done.

Comment: i have posted this question to keep in mind that other might use this lines of code. so i haven't put code in question. this is for knowledge base. hope you understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By This lines of code i am able to get all combinations.

```
function getCombinations(chars) {
    var result = [];
    var f = function (prefix, chars) {
        for (var i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
            if (prefix == '') result.push(prefix + chars[i]);
            else result.push(parseInt(prefix) + parseInt(chars[i]));
            if (prefix == '') f((prefix + chars[i]), chars.slice(i + 1));
            else f((parseInt(prefix) + parseInt(chars[i])), chars.slice(i + 1));
        }
    }
    f('', chars);
    return result;
}
var combinations = getCombinations(["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"]);
console.log(combinations);
alert(combinations);
```

This might helps others too.

Answer (score 1):

```
var combinations[];
for (var i = 0; i < yourIntArray.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < yourIntArray.length; j++) {
        combinations.push(parseInt(yourIntArray[i]) + parseInt(yourIntArray[j]));
    }
}
```

You may need to modify the inner loop if you want to check for uniqueness.

Answer (score 0):

```
var integers = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 ];
var table = [];

for (var y = 0; y < integers.length; y++) {
    for (var x = 0; x < integers.length; x++) {
        table.push(x + y);
    }
}
```

`table` now contains an array of new integers, in this case from 2 (1 + 1) to 20 (10 + 10).

Comment: this code will give lots of duplicate numbers.

Comment: @Mike Of course it does. 1 + 2 is the same as 2 + 1. You didn't mention anything about what result you exactly wanted.